# How to reduce Google Chrome's CPU usage spikes?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, cpu-usage

I use Google Chrome on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate with a decently fast laptop (4-core i7-3610QM, 16GB RAM, 1TB SSD). I noticed that after starting Google Chrome, it has some clear CPU usage spikes, even though I just two or three light pages open:

[image]

How to reduce Google Chrome's CPU usage spikes?

Overall, Google Chrome doesn't take much CPU, only these spikes are annoying (I use some head tracking device to control the mouse, and the CPU spikes from Google Chrome make it lag once every ~10 seconds, despite the fact I set a low priority to Google Chrome and a high priority to the process that takes care of the head tracking).

Comment: in the Chrome flags, activate ETW output (chrome://flags/#trace-export-events-to-etw) and run github.com/google/UIforETW to capture a xperf trace of the CPU usage. Zip and share the trace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was some crappy Google Chrome extension:

[image]

Disabling it solved the lag issues. I don't know why Google Chrome's task manager didn't show that it was this extension that was taking CPU.

---

Update (2019-11-16): the issue is still present but the crappy Google Chrome extension got converted into a "Chrome App", so make sure to disable that crapware as well:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the amount of Chrome Extensions you have, I would try disabling a few and restarting Chrome to see the effect. Also, you set that browser tab to low priority, not chrome itself.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)